# Как добавить много кода, не отвлекая от вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

Хочу после вопроса привести полный код моего проекта (С#). Но кода много. Нужно, чтобы определенный кусок кода открывался только по желанию читателя вопроса.

Comment: кода не должно быть много, в вопросе должен быть только код касающийся конкретно вопроса, *много кода* можете приложить в виде ссылки на сторонний ресурс

Comment: @Bald А есть внутренний ресурс, куда можно выложит полный код проекта, или весь проект? И потом ссылку вписать. Просто, если послать на сторонний ресурс - заплюют (по крайней мере часто такое видал).

Comment: размещение кода проекта целиком противоречит *духу* ресурса: конкретные вопросы. в вопросе должен быть конкретный вопрос и минимальное кол-во кода, необходимое для воспроизведения описанной в вопросе проблемы. в ином случае действительно могут *заплевать* и в итоге закрыть вопрос

Comment: @Bald Спасибо. Суть идеи понял.

Comment: @Bald, почему не ответом? :)

Comment: @Илья, а **зачем** ты хочешь добавить **полный код** проекта? Ограничение поля в 30000 символов.

Comment: @Grundy Вопрос касается темы, в которой я слабо разбираюсь. Поэтому думаю, что выдернув кусок кода, я приобрету головную боль с добавлением то одного, то другого (по просьбам отвечающих). Получится долгая каша. В общем дожидаться ответа буду дольше.

Comment: @Илья, добавив **абсолютно весь** код ответа вообще не дождешься, из-за банальной лени разбирательства в куче неизвестно что делающего кода

Comment: Не уверен, что люди в самом деле способные помочь, начнут  разбираться в таком скопище вашего кода.

Comment: @Grundy: дело не в лени, а бесполезности для будущих посетителей подобного вопроса,  состоящего из стены кода. Хороший вопрос обязан содержать не больше кода, чем необходимо чтобы показать проблему: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jfs, одно не исключает второго :-)

Comment: @Grundy разница в том что один комментарий источает желчь, а другой имеет хотя бы шанс помочь.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать противоречит самой сути данного ресурса: **Конкретные вопросы**. В вопросе должен быть конкретный вопрос и по необходимости *код*. Кода в вопросе должно быть ровно столько сколько необходимо для воспроизведения проблемы описанной в вопросе. При желании вы можете в тело вопроса вставить ссылку на проект на стороннем ресурсе, но только в качестве *дополнительной информации*.

Comment: И какого, простите, чёрта он может вставить в вопрос ссылку на проект на стороннем ресурсе? Ответы ссылки запрещены, в вопросе должен быть минимальный воспроизводимый пример, всё должно быть направлено на то, чтобы это помогало остальным. А ссылка на проект говорит о том, что должна быть произведена работа по **индивидуальному** осмотру, отладке и консультированию. А это уже совсем не в правилах сего сайта

Comment: где я противоречу выше на писаному: ***В вопросе должен быть конкретный вопрос и по необходимости код. Кода в вопросе должно быть ровно столько сколько необходимо для воспроизведения проблемы описанной в вопросе.*** ссылка на полный проект в теле вопроса ничем не противоречит правилам сайта

Comment: Это заставляет думать как и автора вопроса, так и остальных, что вполне нормально оставить десятки файлов со шматком файлов, что кто-то придет и отладит ему приложение за бесплатно. Тем временем, как для **остальных** это будет бесполезно. А в контексте вопроса, без того шмотка скопища файлов никто даже не знает в чем в итоге причина проблемы и где она была.. Ибо если есть Минимальный воспроизводимый пример, то ссылка на проект уже не нужна. А если нет, то вопрос бесполезен для остальных

Comment: автор может так сделать, но это ни к чему не обязывает. повторюсь если вопрос оформлен в соответствии с правилами(конкретный вопрос с примером кода) то вреда от ссылки на сторонний ресурс в теле вопроса я не вижу.

Comment: Просто данный ответ сбивает с толку. Потому что прочитав `При желании вы можете в вопрос вставить ссылку на проект на стороннем ресурсе` кажется, что предлагается либо mcve либо, при желании, хоть какой-нибудь код и ссылку на проект

Answer (score 5):

Иногда причина ошибки может оказаться вне опубликованного на сайте куска кода, в этом случае отвечающие, если у них есть время и желание разбираться в вашей проблеме, могут сами попросить предоставить им полный код. Также, на ruSO есть метка [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), в вопросах по которой приведение полного кода даже обязательно. В этих случаях, как и сказано участником [Bald](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/179270/bald), **не следует** публиковать код в тексте вопроса, но можно вставить ссылку на сторонний ресурс, где и опубликовать требуемое.

Стоит учесть, что невоспроизводимость ошибки, ставшей причиной вопроса, является достаточным основанием для его закрытия. Не следует обижаться, если подобное произошло, лучше постарайтесь локализовать проблему и уже тогда, если не сможете устранить её самостоятельно, задать новый вопрос. Если кто-то из участников готов предоставить вам в этом помощь - общение с ним можно продолжить в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com).

Вопросы по проблеме, причины которой вы даже не берётесь предположить, лучше не задавать вообще, если только это не вопрос о конкретной ошибке, вроде "Что означает ошибка XXX и чем она может быть вызвана?", но в таких вопросах приводить код излишне.

Если в ходе обсуждения вопроса выяснилось, что ошибка содержалась в другой части кода, или вообще не в коде - не забудьте обновить вопрос, приведя в нём актуальную информацию по проблеме, **даже если верный ответ уже получен и принят**, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение других участников и уберечь вопрос от закрытия. Если вы сами нашли ошибку и исправили её, не стесняйтесь ответить на собственный вопрос - это не только не запрещено, но и всячески поощряется. Помните, что смысл SO не только в том, чтобы дать или получить ответ на вопрос, но и в том, чтобы помочь другим людям, столкнувшимся с той же проблемой после вас.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4245/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/4305#comment14559_4246

Comment: @АлексейШиманский инспекцию кода тоже будем прямо на сайте проводить? А публикация кода **по запросу** отвечающего (то есть, он сам вызвался искать там ошибку) никаким правилам не противоречит, как и ваше право закрыть вопрос с невоспроизводимой ошибкой, впрочем, о чём я отдельно написал.

Comment: Вы почитайте что входит в метку [инспекция кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info) ..... так что да. на сайте..............`А публикация кода по запросу отвечающего` - как это поможет в дальнейшем остальным посетителем, которые не поймут в чем была причина и как это исправлять?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а давайте вы, сначала, **прочтёте** мой ответ, а уже потом будете его комментировать:

"Если в ходе обсуждения вопроса выяснилось, что ошибка содержалась в другой части кода, или вообще не в коде - не забудьте обновить вопрос, приведя в нём актуальную информацию по проблеме, даже если верный ответ уже получен и принят"