# Как правильно залить код сайта для вопроса?

Tags: поддержка

Как правильно залить код сайта для того, чтобы задать вопрос на Stack Overflow?
У страницы много PHP-элементов, которые импортируются через `include`, поэтому будет проблематично слегка.
Объединить всё в простой html-код?

Comment: Зачем заливать весь сайт? Показывайте именно проблемный код.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan например, у меня вопрос по позиционированию меню на сайте. Меню импортируется через php. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это оформить?)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Если проблема с отображением в браузере - причём тут php?

Comment: если проблема с меню, которое импортируется, заливайте кусок кода меню. Например кусок кода из header.php.

Comment: Смежные вопросы: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987) *нет, нельзя* и [Как добавить много кода, не отвлекая от вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4245/213987) *никак*

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос должен быть лаконичен. Если для решения проблемы требуется изучить большой объём кода, то такой вопрос скорее всего требует закрытия по причине отсутствия [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

При этом, для упрощения решения проблем веб-разработки на сайте есть механизм [сниппетов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/176217), позволяющий удобно объединить связанные сущности и продемонстрировать проблему в комплексе.